# How to set the color only for the result of mapping vim function?

Tags: vim, neovim

I've got this on my vimrc:

```
nmap <F3> i<C-R>=strftime("%Y-%a-%m-%d %I:%M %R")<CR><Esc>
imap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%a-%m-%d %I:%M %R")<CR>
```

When I press F3 on vim editor, it returns something like datetime.
But I don't know how can I set a different color for this.

I found some other functions that seems do it on https://manpages.debian.org but I don't know for sure...  Any idea?

Comment: Color? But the mappings just insert text into the buffer, it isn't different from if you typed it out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are calling in your mapping is not an external function/command/whatever: it is a Vim function that only returns plain text, without any highlighting information whatsoever.

This has two consequences:

- all the manpages you will find on that site are irrelevant,
- you will have to handle that highlighting yourself, *in Vim*, outside of those mappings.

**First**, you could simplify your pair of mappings a bit:

```
inoremap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%a-%m-%d %I:%M %R")<CR>
nmap <F3> i<F3><Esc>
```

**Second**: if it is a one-shot, you can get away with something like the following:

```
:match Directory /\d\{4}-\w\{3}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}\s\d\{2}:\d\{2}\s\d\{2}:\d\{2}/
```

which matches a date as returned by your `:help strftime()` call and assigns it to the default `Directory` highlight group (that's the first one that came to mind):

[image]

See `:help :match`.

**Third**, if you want it to be automatic, you will have to delve a little more into syntax highlighting, which is a two-steps process:

1. you define syntax groups with `:help syntax`,
2. you apply visual attributes to those groups with `:help :highlight`.

Assuming you want this to happen in buffers with filetype `foo`, you can create `~/.vim/after/syntax/foo.vim` where you can define your own syntax group:

```
syntax match MyDate /\d\{4}-\w\{3}-\d\{2}-\d\{2}\s\d\{2}:\d\{2}\s\d\{2}:\d\{2}/
```

and link it to a default group:

```
highlight link MyDate Directory
```

If you prefer to handle the visual attributes of that specific highlight group yourself, you can follow the method described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f).